# Find a Recurrence Relation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations, recursive-algorithms

I want to find a recurrence relation for number of decimal numbers with length n, (we called $a_0$ ) that not includes 0 and any combination of 11,12, 21.

i see the result is:

$a_n=15a_{n-2}+7a_{n-1}$

How this was calculated? any hint or idea highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $\alpha\lt \beta$ be the roots of 
$$x^2-15x-7=0,$$
we have
$$a_{n+1}-\alpha a_n=\beta(a_n-\alpha a_{n-1})=\cdots=\beta^n(a_1-\alpha a_0),$$
$$a_{n+1}-\beta a_n=\alpha(a_n-\beta a_{n-1})=\cdots=\alpha^n(a_1-\beta a_0).$$
Subtracting the latter from the former gives us
$$(\beta-\alpha)a_n=\beta^n(a_1-\alpha a_0)-\alpha^n(a_1-\beta a_0)$$
i.e.
$$a_n=\frac{\beta^n(a_1-\alpha a_0)-\alpha^n(a_1-\beta a_0)}{\beta-\alpha}$$
where
$$\alpha=\frac{15-\sqrt{253}}{2},\ \ \ \beta=\frac{15+\sqrt{253}}{2}.$$

P.S. By [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have
$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{-15}{1}=15,\ \ \ \alpha\beta=\frac{-7}{1}=-7.$$
Hence, you'll see that 
$$a_{n+1}-\alpha a_n=\beta(a_n-\alpha a_{n-1})$$
$$a_{n+1}-\beta a_n=\alpha(a_n-\beta a_{n-1})$$
are the same as 
$$a_{n+1}=15a_n+7a_{n-1}.$$

Comment: wow ! nice solution, but from alpha, beta how we get the 15an_2+7an_1?

Comment: @user153695: I added a bit. Did I answer your question?

Comment: yes MATHLOVE. I LOVE YOU. i approve and vote-up

Comment: @user153695: You are welcome!

Comment: how you calculate the $x^2-15x+7$?

Comment: @user153695: For $ax^2+bx+c=0\ (a\not=0)$, we have$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}.$$

Comment: i means, it's related to my question?

Comment: @user153695: Yes, in general, if you have $pa_{n+1}+qa_n+ra_{n-1}=0$, then consider the roots of $px^2+qx+r=0$ like my answer.

Comment: you maybe wrong, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189599/recurrence-formula-for-number-of-decimal-numbers-with-some-restrictions

Comment: @mathlove, are u see ?

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura: I corrected a sign typo in my answer.

Comment: you answer is very wrong...

Comment: ???????????????????????

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura: I see that my answer is wrong, but an *accepted* answer cannot be deleted. So, you should post your answer here.

Comment: another answer in another link is correcT?