# recurrence formula for number of decimal numbers with some restrictions

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, combinations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I ran into a Olympiad Question that so difficult,

if $a_n$ be the number of decimal numbers with length $n$ that has no $0$ in the digits and also has not any combinations $11,12,21$, I want to find a recurrence for $a_n$. My note says:

$a_n=15a_{n-2}+7a_{n-1} $

I think this is not correct, anyone could help me to verify me and describe it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want binary strings from an alphabet of $9$ digits that don't have $11,12$ or $21$.

Let's try to count these:

How many don't end in $0$ or $1$? For any sequence of length $n-1$ without the prohibited  subsequence we can can add any of the $7$ digits $3,4,\dots 9$ at the end without having to worry. Thus there are $7a_{n-1}$.

How many sequences end in $1$? If a sequence ends in $1$ the digit before it is not $1$ or $2$. there are $7$ options for the digit before the $1$. And then we use the same argument as before to conlude there are $a_{n-2}$ possibilities for the sequence formed by all digits except the last two.

How many sequences end in $2$? There are two options, when the digit before the $2$ is not $2$ we can be sure it is not $1$ either, and we get $7a_{n-2}$.

Therefore there are $14a_{n-2}+7a_{n-1}$  desired sequences that do not end in $22$. So we must only add the number of sequences that end in $22$. But these are less than $a_{n-2}$. So I think it is wrong too.

---

I don't know if this helps but if $b_n$ is the number of desired sequences of length $n$ ending in $2$ we get:

$a_n=7a_{n-1}+14a_{n-2}+b_{n-1}$

$b_n=7a_{n-2}+b_{n-1}$

Although this does give us:

$a_n=7a_{n-1}+14_{n-2}+7(a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}+\dots a_{1})+b_2$

and since $b_2=8$ we get:

$a_n=7(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+\dots a_1)+8+7a_{n-2}$

Comment: what is the final recurrence you think ?

Comment: are you sure $22$ is not forbidden?

Comment: yes, just 11,12,21

Comment: $a_n=7a_{n-1}+14a_{n-2}+p_{n-2}+1, a_0=1, a_1=9, P_n= \Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1}7a_i$

Comment: am i right ?????

Comment: what is $p_n$??

Comment: i wrote it ....

Comment: well, we got almost the same thing, although I got the same answer as you plus $7$.

Comment: My formula works for getting $a_3$.

Comment: you means your formula is the same with me?

Comment: they are almost the same, but I add $7$ to what you have.

Comment: the last sentence in is your recurrence, am i right ?

Comment: wait...... i found this question on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957883/find-a-recurrence-relation/957897#957897

Comment: Yes, the last sentence is the recurrence.

Comment: see the same question on that link, is it false?

Comment: The recurrence relation cannot be $15a_{n-2}+7a_{n-1}$ because that answer makes sense when adding $22$ at the end always works, but this isn't the case. So that recurrence gives values of $a_n$ that are larger than in reality.

Comment: 15a_{n-2} not 25

Comment: yeah, sorry for that.

Comment: Would you please see the correction that created on : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957883/find-a-recurrence-relation  is it okey ?

Comment: The answer is still wrong, and it is not only slightly wrong, it is very wrong, it even switches $a_{n}$ and $a_{n-1}$. In conclusion it will give numbers that are way too big.

Answer (score 0):

$a_1 = 9 \\
a_2 = 81-3=78$

To assemble the numbers for $a_n$, we can take any of those for $a_{n-1}$ and add digits $3..9$ without problems ($7a_{n-1}$). To get the numbers that end in $2$ or $1$, we can take any numbers from $a_{n-2}$ and add digits $X1$ or $Y2$, where $X$ is $3..9$ and $Y$ is $2..9$ ($15a_{n-2}$). These two terms match the formula as given.

---

As pointed out in comments, this gives a case when there is an embedded $12$, from the case when adding "$22$" to a number that previously ended in $1$. This shows that the recurrence is incorrectly overcounting the possibilities.

I don't see any easy way to rescue the recurrence from there. A multiple-state counter works fine but is obviously more complicated than is looked for here.

Comment: so, what is the final recurrence ?

Comment: but if you add $2$ you can run into problems if there is a $1$ at the end.

Comment: if you add 22 to then end of the sequence 3451 you get 345122 which contains 12 and is forbidden-

Comment: wait...... i found this question on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957883/find-a-recurrence-relation/957897#957897

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Hmm... very true; it looks like the recurrence is wrong, then.